# Do I need to provide a "from" email address while using Heroku + SendGrid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, sendgrid

I have the standard setup in `config/environments/production.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "myapp.heroku.com" }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :addresses            => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port                 => '587',
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :user_name            => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password             => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain               => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true  
  }
```

However, I encountered the following error while trying to send a mail:

`ArgumentError: An SMTP From address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_from, return_path, sender, or from address.`

I then tried using the email I found on my heroku add-on page, i.e. `app######@heroku.com`, but now I got

`Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)`

So do I need to specify a from email or not? If yes, which one should I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you need to set a from address.  All emails need an from address specified.

```
:from => "address_you_are_sending_from@your_domain.com"
```

This needs to be set in your _mailer.rb file. You can also set it gloablly in an initiallizer but it must always be referenced in your_mailer.rb files, and within each mail method itself.

You should change the :domain to a domain that you control.  But if you were to use Heroku would your apps address not be yourapp.herokuapp.com instead of yourapp.heroku.com?

Comment: Do you mean I have to sign up for a gmail account and use it as the email for example? But if so, then how can I supply the gmail username and password?

Answer (score 9):

Try this code in your `production.rb` file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_options = { from: "my_address@example.com" }
```

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a from address in your mailer file.

For example if you have an **admin_mailer.rb** for notifying your personal email of new activity on your site, it could look like this:

```
  def new_customer_trial(customer_object)
    @new_customer = customer_object
    mail :to => "me@personal_email.com", :subject => "New Customer Trial", :from => "'My Site Notifications' <notifications@my_site.com>"
  end
```

And you'd send that mail from a controller:

```
AdminMailer.new_customer_trial(customer_object)
```

or as a delayed job:

```
AdminMailer.delay.new_customer_trial(customer_object)
```